# Prove any DFA with k<2^n states does not accept the strings with an odd number of some character

Tags: automata, finite-automata, automata-theory

Let the language L_n have character set Sigma = {a_1, ..., a_n}.  L_n has exactly those words which contain some character an odd number of times.  Equivalently if L_n^i is the language with each word containing an odd number of a_i then L_n = L_n^1 union ...union L_n^n.

I have already produced an NFA that accepts L_n and a DFA of 2^n states which does as well.

I now need to prove that this is the smallest DFA accepting this language.  I am given the hint to suppose that there is a DFA of k < 2^n states which accepts L_n, and then show that there are some strings *u, v* in Sigma^* where *u* contains *a* and odd number of times, *v* contains it an even number of times, and the DFA must terminate on both at the same state.

I've been trying to take the 2^n as a strong hint, like maybe consider all strings of length n, but there are n^n of these.  Maybe consider all strings of length n using only characters *a,b*.  Since there are k < 2^n states, then some two strings like this must be sent to the same state.  The rejected strings in this set are those with even numbers of *a* and *b* but I have no way of knowing if two such instances of these go to the same state, or if they did, how that would even matter.

Maybe consider all choices of strings where a_1 occurs either once or 0 times, and a_2 occurs once or 0 times, etc.  There are 2^n choices of these so some 2 of these must go to the same state.  The only string not in the language here is the empty string.  Still I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Each of a_i appears either an odd number of times or an even number of times in any given input string. For any given string, there is a shortest string whose symbols are in lexicographical order which, if appended to the given string, results in a string not in the language. That string will have at most one of each alphabet symbol, in order by index, so as to make the parity of all symbol counts even.

This means that every one of the 2^n parity configurations is distinguishable w.r.t. the Myhill-Nerode indistinguishability relation; there are 2^n classes for this language, so a minimal DFA must have 2^n states.

I think this is essentially what your intuition was, just restated to make explicit use of Myhill-Nerode and the indistinguishability relationship.

Edit: adding an example to make this clearer.

Consider the alphabet {a, b, c}. Then in any string, each of a, b and c appear either an even number of times or an odd number of times. Consider the 2^3 = 8 shortest strings with symbols in lexicographically sorted order which cover every possible case:

1. e: all strings appear an even number of times
2. a: a appears an odd number of times, b and c an even number of times
3. b: same as a, but b
4. c: same as a and b, but c
5. ab: a and b appear an odd number of times, c appears an even number of times
6. ac: same as ab, but ac
7. bc: same as ab and ac, but bc
8. abc: a, b and c all appear an odd number of times

For each of these shortest strings covering all parity configurations, there is a corresponding shortest string with symbols in lexicographically sorted order which causes the concatenation to have an even number of all symbols. A moment's reflection shows that the shortest such string is the same as the shortest string that represents the class: for each of the 8 shortest representatives above, concatenating with itself produces a string with an even number of occurrences of all symbols and there can be no shorted string producing the same effect.

1. e.e = e
2. a.a = aa
3. b.b = bb
4. c.c = cc
5. ab.ab = abab
6. ac.ac = acac
7. bc.bc = bcbc
8. abc.abc = abcabc

In terms of Myhill-Nerode, the equivalence class [x] must differ from the equivalence class [y], since the shortest string that can follow a string in [x] and not lead to a string in L is x, whereas the shortest string that can follow a string in [y] and not lead to a string in L is y, and we have already required that x and y be different. We can confirm for our 8 cases:

1. e.a, e.b, e.c, e.ab., e.ac, e.bc, e.abc each have at least one symbol appearing an odd number of times (a, b, c, a, a, b, a)
2. a.e, a.b, a.c, a.ab, a.ac, a.bc, a.abc each have at least one symbol appearing an odd number of times (a, a, a, b, c, a, b)
3. b.e, b.a, b.c, b.ab, b.ac, b.bc, b.abc each have at least one symbol appearing an odd number of times (b, a, b, a, a, c, a)
4. c.e, c.a, c.b, c.ab, c.ac, c.bc, c.abc each have at least one symbol appearing an odd number of times (c, a, b, a, a, b, a)
5. ab.e, ab.a, ab.b, ab.c, ab.ac, ab.bc, ab.abc each have at least one symbol appearing an odd number of times (a, b, a, a, b, a, c)
6. ac.e, ac.a, ac.b, ac.c, ac.ab, ac.bc, ac.abc each have at least one symbol appearing an odd number of times (a, c, a, a, b, a, b)
7. bc.e, bc.a, bc.b, bc.c, bc.ab, bc.ac, bc.abc each have at least one symbol appearing an odd number of times (b, a, c, b, a, a, a)
8. abc.e, abc.a, abc.b, abc.c, abc.ab, abc.ac, abc.bc each have at least one symbol appearing an odd number of times (a, b, a, a, c, b, a)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with the string "a_1 occurs either once or 0 times..." is good. But look at them as the ends of your strings like this:

Suppose you have read an input string and are in state q.

1. Suppose the input string has even numbers of all symbols. Then all the continuations that have at least one symbol (occuring once and thus making its number of occurrences odd) should lead to acceptance, the others (here only the empty string) not.
2. Suppose the input string has even numbers of all symbols except a_1. Then all the continuations that do not contain a_1 OR contain a_1 and have at least one symbol other than a_1 should lead to acceptance, the others not.
3. ...

You arrive at exactly 2^n different situations and different sets of strings that should lead to acceptance/rejection. Thus the state q must be different in each of the situations and therefore there have to be at least 2^n of them.